# How to build LINQ queries for NHibernate which contain function calls?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

A few weeks ago I decided to switch from using Linq to SQL to use NHibernate instead. (Reasons include: other Java-based projects use Hibernate; target DB not yet decided; multiple DBs may have to be targeted)

Anyway, I wanted to continue using LINQ and saw that NHibernate has LINQ support. I want to have a small nummber of object access methods and be able to pass a LINQ expression which filters the query but it has not worked as expected.

Here is an example based on the `PredicateBuilder` from http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

```
public static Expression<Func<Product, bool>> ContainsInDescription(params string[] keys)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();
    foreach (string keyword in keys)
    {
        string temp = keyword.ToLower();
        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Description.Contains(temp));
    }
    return predicate;
}
```

The `Predicate.False` statment causes the following error message:

```
Atf.NUnit.Model.TestLinq.TestProductCID():
System.Exception : Could not determine member type from Constant, False, System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression
```

The `p.Description.Contains` statement causes this error message:

```
Atf.NUnit.Model.TestLinq.TestProductCID():
System.Exception : Could not determine member type from Invoke, Invoke(p => p.Description.Contains(value(Atf.Model.Linq.ProductLinq+<>c__DisplayClass2).temp), f), System.Linq.Expressions.InvocationExpression
```

I get similar errors when using `string.Equals` and other such methods.

Am I doing something wrong here? Should I use a different approach?

Comment: Sorry, no. The project got cancelled ;-)

Comment: A Zen solution:) Thanks for the response.